# Question about the Bag of Endless Caltrops

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I don't recall seeing anything about caltrops obtained from a Bag of Endless Caltrops disappearing. Does that mean you could in theory stockpile these caltrops by regularly removing them from the bag, storing them separately, letting the bag's supply regenerate, and repeating?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes, you can.

As you say, the caltrops are not described as ever disappearing, and are in fact stated to “follow all the rules of for normal caltrops.” The item requires *Leomund’s secret chest* to make, which implies that it’s basically just literally an extradimensional space full of perfectly normal, mundane caltrops that you can draw at will. Maybe there’s a Hemi-demi-semi-plane of Caltrops somewhere.

At any rate, it’s not much of an exploit; caltrops aren’t exactly amazing. The sheer amount of time this takes prevents you from doing much with it most situations.

Comment: I just thought being able to stockpile caltrops for covering large areas in single turns might be useful. ...and now I also picture rolling purple on a Prismatic spell sending someone to the Demielemental Plane of Caltrops.

Comment: @Cobalt Well yes, that's exactly what the bag is for. That ability isn't terribly useful much of the time, which is why it's 800 gp for the thing. That's still a pretty large mark-up from normal bags of caltrops, but it's small in the overall scheme of things because you rarely get that kind of time.

Comment: @Cobalt A little like the [World of Shrimp](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Shrimp_Worlds)

Answer (score 9):

I don't see why not.  Generally nonmagical objects created by conjuration spells are permanent.  The bag radiates conjuration magic; the caltrops produced are nonmagical.

The bag costs 800gp, 5 handfuls of caltrops would cost 5gp.  No balance concern there.  (And if you want to consider the economic ramifications of magic in the D&D verse, this bag is the least of your problems.)

Comment: So *very* true about the economics.

Comment: "And in the millennia to follow, the Caltrop Retrievers' Cult did anything in its power to bring woe and ruin to this world. They pulled and pulled tons of caltrops from their unholy bags until the face of the Earth could no longer be seen under the mountains of rusted caltrops. Welcome to Caltrop World!"

Comment: @Xabei - Ah, the long awaited [Caltrop event horizon](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Shoe_Event_Horizon).